# Change executable path of Run/Debug configuration in Rider IDE for web project

Tags: iis-express, rider

In the Rider IDE for a web project I want to change the Executable path (see red area in attached screenshot) in the Run/Debug configuration. The text-field is grayed out and after playing around a bit I didn't find a way to change this.

Is there a way to change this option?

Is it not yet implemented (did not find it yet in the issue tracker)?

[image: Screenshot of Run/Debug Configurations]

What I want to do is change the path such that it points to the 32-bit version of IIS-Express as the given web project references an old 32-bit C++ library, hence the project has to run as 32-bit process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use 
DotNet Executable run/debug configuration and set wherever exe you need.

Comment: Nevertheless it would nice if there was a 32-bit option in the DotNet Project configuration.